# Is container format relevant to security of encrypted message inside?

Tags: protocol-design

Still **[trying to design a fully binary cryptography container format for my mobile app](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11489/12164)**, I am here asking if container is ever relevant.

Thanks to Apple, I cannot use GPG directly because I can neither call GPG through GPGME (`fork(2)` is not allowed) nor embed it (license conflicts)

The container format is simple `ar(1)` format that store its contents in plaintext, probably then compressed with some algorithm like Gzip. I am wondering if the container format affects the security of the already encrypted data, the MAC and IV that is held as separate entities within.

The plan is to use AES-CTR (or AES-CFB, or AES-OFB, or my homebrew cipher SHA512-HMAC-OFB which turned out to be just as fast as AES thanks to its larger block size) to encrypt the data and put it in the archive file (`data.obj` in the archive), its initialization vector in plain (`iv.bin`), asymmetrically encrypted symmetric key (`key.bin`, if relevant), the SHA512-HMAC of the archive in "check archive" form that is described below (`mac.bin`) and some metadata (algorithms used, compression of plaintext used, probably a user supplied tag in plain text) in plain (`info.json`)

**EDIT**

`ar(1)` format stores file name (up to 16 characters), owner UID/GID, modification time, file mode (permissions) in its file header.

MAC (or signature) is calculated on a "check archive": every entity except the MAC (or signature) itself are in the check archive, which is also in `ar(1)` format, sorted in binary order based on their file names, retaining all their properties (name, owner, modification date and file mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the comments to an answer…

[Ricky Demer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/991/ricky-demer):

> "algorithms used" should be stored with the *key*(s).  "compression of plaintext used, probably a user supplied tag" should go into the MAC.

[Maxthon Chan](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/8492/maxthon-chan):

> That is, algorithm should not appear in the container at all, and everything that is not MAC itself should be included in MAC?

[Ricky Demer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/991/ricky-demer):

> Yes. Also note that compression [may be problematic](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2188/991).

[Maxthon Chan](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/8492/maxthon-chan):

> I forgot the asymmetrically encrypted symmetric key may appear in the file as well as key.bin. How to deal with that?

[Ricky Demer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/991/ricky-demer):

> If you're using public keys too, then you should probably use digital signatures, possibly instead of a MAC.